# Deriving zero for a wave function

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a function  of the type:

$f(3,t) = k_1 e^{i\pi\frac{t}{2}} + k_2 e^{i\pi\frac{t}{3}} + k_3 e^{i\pi\frac{t}{5}}$

The divider in $\frac{t}{n}$ is in fact a prime and $f(n,t)$ indicates addition of first $n$ prime dividers.

I need to derive solutions for $f(n,t)=0$ such that,
-> $t$ is a real number (and not complex number)
-> $k_n$ is a weighted factor of $n$-th prime.

How do  I do it??

Thanks and regards

Comment: I would say $f_3(t)$.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand??